# Optimizing the code for Cascaded Biquad Filters

Tags: c, optimization, simd, intrinsics, neon

1I have a 3 stage biquad filter to filter the input signal data (input). While optimizing, I unrolled the entire loop and used load (vld1_s32), multiply-accumulate (vmlal_s32) intrinsics thinking that this optimization will reduce the time spent by the CPU on the code. But, I didn't get better results. Is it possible to optimize the following code in any other way using ARM NEON Intrinsics (SIMD architecture)?

Note: Values of buffer (x) and coefficients (h) are 32-bit integers.

```
long long int sum;
for(i1=0;i1<100;i1++)
{
    temp = input[i1];//32 bit (int) datatype

    for(i=0;i<3;i++)
    {
       sum = x[1+2*i] * h[1+5*i];
       sum += x[3+2*i] * h[3+5*i];
       sum = sum<<1; //center tapping
       sum += x[2+2*i] * h[2+5*i];
       sum += x[4+2*i] * h[4+5*i];
       sum += temp * h[0+5*i];

       x[2+2*i] = x[1+2*i];
       x[1+2*i] = temp;
       temp = sum>>31; 
    }
    printf("%lld\n",temp);
}
```

Optimized code: (i believe it's only partial optimization)

```
    int32x2_t x_vec,h_vec;
    int64x2_t result_vec;
    for(i1=0;i1<100;i1++)
    {
       temp =input[i1];

       for (i = 0; i < 3; i++)
       {
          result_vec = vdupq_n_s64(0);

          for (j = 0; j < 2; j++) // 5 coefficients in total for a biquad - 4 used here
          {
            x_vec = vld1_s32(&x[1 + 2 * i + 2 * j]);
            h_vec = vld1_s32(&h[1 + 5 * i + 2 * j]);
            result_vec = vmlal_s32(result_vec, x_vec, h_vec);
          }

          sum = vadd_s64(result_vec[0], result_vec[1]);
          sum = sum + temp * h[0 + 5 * i])  //- remaining one used here
          sum += x[1 + 2 * i] * h[1 + 5 * i]);//adding one more time
          sum += x[3 + 2 * i] * h[3 + 5 * i];//adding one more time

          x[2 + 2 * i] = x[1 + 2 * i];
          x[1 + 2 * i] = temp;
          temp = sum>>31;
       }
       printf("%d\n",temp);
    }
```

Comment: Which processor you are using? SIMD instructions depends on data width and number of data. Usually you have to pad the data (if it is not of desired length) for multiply-accumulate instruction.

Comment: @svtag ARM Cortex A7. I believe that i used proper intrinsics.

Comment: Instead of doing micro-optimizations, you might consider going to the GPU and benefit from its many cores.

Comment: Does Cortex A7 have any out-of-order exec?  If no, you might be bottlenecking on latency and need to do software pipelining.  Or unaligned loads might be a problem.  Did you compile with optimization enabled?

Comment: @PeterCordes Yes, I compiled with O2 level compiler optimization.

Comment: You have to redesign the code completely. You should look deeper into the instructions `vld3` `vld4` first.

Comment: In `sum += x[2+2*i] * h[2+2*i];` is that last 2 supposed to be a 5?

Comment: @technosaurus.. Yes, you are correct.